# un elemento desaparece pero no vuelve a aparecer. Por que? fadeOut() fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un texto que al hacer click en un boton quiero que desaparezca, se reemplace por otro y vuelva a aparecer, para eso uso las funciones fadeOut y fadeIn de jQuery. El problema es que al hacer click en el boton en ocasiones funciona correctamente pero en otras el texto solo desaparece y no vuelve a aparecer.
Por que sucede esto y como puedo arreglarlo?

**codigo:**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#botonFrases').click(function(){
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arrayFrase.length + 1));

      $('#frases').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $('#frases').html('<p>'+'"'+arrayFrase[i][0]+'"'+'</p>').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('#autor').fadeOut("slow", function(){
      $('#autor').html('<p>'+arrayFrase[i][1]+'</p>').fadeIn("slow");
    });
  }); 
});
```

(cada elemento de arrayFrase es otro array cuyos elementos son la frase y el autor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Còdigo resuleto:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

  $('#botonFrases').click(function(){
    var arrayFrase = ['uno', 'dos'];
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arrayFrase.length));
      $("#log").html("Posiciòn: " + i);
      $('#frases').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $('#frases').html('<p>'+'"'+arrayFrase[i]+'"'+'</p>').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('#autor').fadeOut("slow", function(){
      $('#autor').html('<p>'+arrayFrase[i]+'</p>').fadeIn("slow");
    });
  }); 

});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="botonFrases">Frases</button>
<div id="frases">Inicio</div>
<div id="autor">Inicio</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Nota: El div "log" lo agreguè solo para fines de debugear la soluciòn.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tu còdigo està incompleto y tiene algunas cosas de màs... no sè si es lo que buscas pero en este link està arreglado el còdigo y ademàs funcional.

https://codepen.io/logoys/pen/rJgjmb

Comment: como sugerencia . deberías de poner el código en tu respuesta ya que los enlaces tienden a caducar . y eso no aporta para que la respuesta dure . saludes

Comment: Por que pones los acentos al revés xd